# Im installing BiocManager in R and its taking a long time? Why is that?

Tags: r, bioconductor

[image]

I left this to run overnight however, it is still loading. Is there something I can do to speed up the process or is there something else I can try. I'm not sure why its taking so long.

Comment: It appears that BiocManager loaded but was unable to find a package named "Enhanced Volcano".

Comment: It doesn't usually make sense to install packages in an R Markdown document.  You should install them before processing the document.